# Where am I going wrong in solving $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf w}(\mathbf y - \mathbf X\mathbf w)^T(\mathbf y - \mathbf X \mathbf w) = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I have the following equation which I wish to solve:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf w}(\mathbf y - \mathbf X\mathbf w)^T(\mathbf y - \mathbf X \mathbf w) = 0$$

Here $\mathbf y_{n*1}, \mathbf X_{n*2},\mathbf w_{2*1},$

My solution (done on paper because MathJax is a bit difficult for me to use):

[image]

Also, is my reasoning for step 4 correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line $3$ to line $4$, note that 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w} (y^TXw) = X^Ty,
$$
then you'll get the right answer 
$$
\hat{w} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.
$$

Explicit derivation:
Note that
$$
y^TXw = w_1\sum_{i=1}^ny_i + w_2\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_{1i}+\cdots+w_p\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_{pi},
$$
taking derivative w.r.t vector $w$, $w \in \mathbb{R}^p$, will result in a gradient, i.e., vector with $p$ rows and $1$ column, namely 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum y_i \\
\sum y_i x_{1i}\\ 
\vdots \\
\sum y_i x_{pi}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the $j$th row is the derivative of $y^TXw$ w.r.t. $w_j$.
Now, as $X^T$ is $p\times n$ and $y$ is $n \times 1$, hence $X^Ty$ is $p \times 1$ as required.

Comment: Can you please explain why? I thought it would be y'X. I can see from the order of the matrices that my solution is wrong and that yours is correct. But in general, how do I solve such problems involving matrix calculus. My current method is assuming each element of the matrix and then finding the partial derivative

Comment: @rjmessibarca Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

No your reasoning in step 4 is wrong. For example if $X$ is a square matrix, $\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}$ will not be a scalar. Therefore your result is wrong. Do note that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{w}} \left(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w} \right) = 2 \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w}$$

I am sure that you can get to the right answer from here.

Comment: $X$ is an $n \times 2$ matrix, so $X^TX$ is $2\times2$.

Comment: Yes, so not a scalar.

Comment: Yes, I'm just disagreeing with the "If X is a square matrix" bit in your answer. It does not have to be square, though $X^TX$ will be.

Comment: Ooh yeah I know about that, I was just giving an example to show why this was not true but I'll clarify.

Comment: @Jan How did you get that result? BTW, I used the expression that you mentioned in step 5. But still answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M = \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w}$

and $f = M^T M = M : M$.

We will utilize the following the identities

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ or $$A^T:B={\rm tr}(AB)$$
- Cyclic property of Trace/Frobenius product $$\eqalign{
  A:BC
   &= AC^T:B \cr
   &= B^TA:C \cr
   &= {\text etc.} \cr
  }$$

Now, we obtain the differential first and thereafter we obtain the gradient.

So, 
\begin{align}
df &= \left( d M: M \right) + \left( M : dM \right)\\
   &= 2M : dM \\
   &= 2M : \left( - \mathbf{X} d \mathbf{w} \right) \\   
   &= - 2\mathbf{X}^T M \ : \ d \mathbf{w} \hspace{8mm} \text{note: utilized cyclic property of Frobenius product}  \\
   &= - 2\mathbf{X}^T \left(  \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w} \right) \ : \ d \mathbf{w} \ .
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient reads
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{w}} f 
= - 2\mathbf{X}^T \left(  \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w} \right) \ .
\end{align}

Then you can set the gradient to $0$ and obtain your $$\mathbf{w} = \left( \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \right) ^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y}$$

Comment: I did not ask for how to solve. I asked what is wrong with my solution.